# Truncating date + time using DateTime2

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, datetime

I have been using this format for years to truncate dates and times

```
SELECT  DATEADD(HOUR, DATEDIFF(HOUR, 0, '1980-02-05 12:45'), 0) AS Hour ,
        DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, '1980-02-05 12:45'), 0) AS Day ,
        DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, '1980-02-05 12:45'), 0) AS Month ,
        DATEADD(YEAR, DATEDIFF(YEAR, 0, '1980-02-05 12:45'), 0) AS Year;
```

But I have a need to store very early dates like `1400-01-01` and therefore I can use `DateTime2`.

But how would I support the ability to still truncate like above using `DateTime2`?

Changing the year above to `1400` from `1980` will then result in

```
SELECT  DATEADD(HOUR, DATEDIFF(HOUR, 0, '1400-02-05 12:45'), 0) AS Hour ,
        DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, '1400-02-05 12:45'), 0) AS Day ,
        DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, '1400-02-05 12:45'), 0) AS Month ,
        DATEADD(YEAR, DATEDIFF(YEAR, 0, '1400-02-05 12:45'), 0) AS Year;
```

> The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted
>   in an out-of-range value.

SO casting to `DateTime2`

```
SELECT  DATEADD(HOUR, DATEDIFF(HOUR, 0, CAST('1400-02-05 12:45' AS DATETIME2)),0) AS Hour ,
        DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, CAST('1400-02-05 12:45' AS DATETIME2)),0) AS Day ,
        DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, CAST('1400-02-05 12:45' AS DATETIME2)), 0) AS Month ,
        DATEADD(YEAR, DATEDIFF(YEAR, 0, CAST('1400-02-05 12:45' AS DATETIME2)), 0) AS Year;
```

> The conversion of a datetime2 data type to a datetime data type
>   resulted in an out-of-range value.

I am assuming that the `0` is being treated as a `DateTime` data type and effectly casting it to `DateTime`.

Trying to cast the `0` to `DateTime2` using `CAST(0 AS DATETIME2)` gives me this error

> Explicit conversion from data type int to datetime2 is not allowed.

In the end I am wanting to use these as persisted columns in a table which worked fine with `DateTime` data types but not so easy with `DateTime2`

Comment: Tip: It's helpful to tag database questions with both the appropriate software (MySQL, Oracle, DB2, ...) and version, e.g. `sql-server-2014`. Differences in syntax and features often affect the answers, e.g. [`DateFromParts`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213228.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

You should use some specific base date instead of `0`. `0` can be implicitly converted into `datetime` type. For `datetime2` such implicit conversion is not allowed. In addition, the base date should have a `datetime2` type. Then `DATEDIFF` and `DATEADD` would work with `datetime2` values.

Another reason for using explicit base date is that you need this base date to be the first day of the year and to have `00:00:00` time for the formula to work correctly. Implicit starting dates, like `0` converted to `datetime` or `''` converted to `datetime2` also have these properties right now, but do you really want to rely on internal details of the type implementation? It is better to spell out such things explicitly and it makes the formula easier to understand for a new person.

Besides, if you ever want to truncate to the week boundary using the same approach, then you'd have to pick a base date that is Monday (if your week starts on Monday) or Sunday (if your week starts on Sunday). The formula remains the same, but base date is important.

**Example 1 - works**

```
DECLARE @VarBase datetime2 = '2000-01-01';
DECLARE @VarValue datetime2 = '1400-02-05 12:45';

SELECT
    DATEADD(HOUR,  DATEDIFF(HOUR,  @VarBase, @VarValue), @VarBase) AS Hour,
    DATEADD(DAY,   DATEDIFF(DAY,   @VarBase, @VarValue), @VarBase) AS Day,
    DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, @VarBase, @VarValue), @VarBase) AS Month,
    DATEADD(YEAR,  DATEDIFF(YEAR,  @VarBase, @VarValue), @VarBase) AS Year;
```

**Example 2 - works**

```
SELECT
    DATEADD(HOUR,  DATEDIFF(HOUR,  @VarBase, '1400-02-05 12:45'), @VarBase) AS Hour,
    DATEADD(DAY,   DATEDIFF(DAY,   @VarBase, '1400-02-05 12:45'), @VarBase) AS Day,
    DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, @VarBase, '1400-02-05 12:45'), @VarBase) AS Month,
    DATEADD(YEAR,  DATEDIFF(YEAR,  @VarBase, '1400-02-05 12:45'), @VarBase) AS Year;
```

**Example 3 - doesn't work**

```
SELECT
    DATEADD(HOUR,  DATEDIFF(HOUR,  '2000-01-01', '1400-02-05 12:45'), '2000-01-01') AS Hour,
    DATEADD(DAY,   DATEDIFF(DAY,   '2000-01-01', '1400-02-05 12:45'), '2000-01-01') AS Day,
    DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, '2000-01-01', '1400-02-05 12:45'), '2000-01-01') AS Month,
    DATEADD(YEAR,  DATEDIFF(YEAR,  '2000-01-01', '1400-02-05 12:45'), '2000-01-01') AS Year;
```

> Adding a value to a 'datetime' column caused an overflow.

It doesn't work, because literal `2000-01-01` is converted into `datetime`, not `datetime2`.

**Example 4 - works**

```
SELECT
    DATEADD(HOUR,  DATEDIFF(HOUR,  CAST('2000-01-01' AS datetime2), '1400-02-05 12:45'), CAST('2000-01-01' AS datetime2)) AS Hour,
    DATEADD(DAY,   DATEDIFF(DAY,   CAST('2000-01-01' AS datetime2), '1400-02-05 12:45'), CAST('2000-01-01' AS datetime2)) AS Day,
    DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, CAST('2000-01-01' AS datetime2), '1400-02-05 12:45'), CAST('2000-01-01' AS datetime2)) AS Month,
    DATEADD(YEAR,  DATEDIFF(YEAR,  CAST('2000-01-01' AS datetime2), '1400-02-05 12:45'), CAST('2000-01-01' AS datetime2)) AS Year;
```

Comment: Thanks - but I have a problem now about it not being deterministic. See my comment on @MegaTron thread

Comment: @ChrisCrowe, I'm glad you found yourself that using `CONVERT` instead of `CAST` solves the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use:

```
DECLARE @Default DATETIME2 = CAST('' AS DATETIME2)
SELECT  DATEADD(HOUR, DATEDIFF(HOUR, @Default, CAST('1400-02-05 12:45' AS DATETIME2)), @Default) AS Hour ,
        DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, @Default, CAST('1400-02-05 12:45' AS DATETIME2)), @Default) AS Day ,
        DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, @Default, CAST('1400-02-05 12:45' AS DATETIME2)), @Default) AS Month ,
        DATEADD(YEAR, DATEDIFF(YEAR, @Default, CAST('1400-02-05 12:45' AS DATETIME2)), @Default) AS Year;
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but I now have a problem with these formulas are non deterministic and can't be persisted to the database.  
  
ALTER TABLE dbo.QuakeRawJSON  
ADD  
 [Date]  AS (dateadd(day,datediff(day,CAST('' AS DATETIME2),origintime),CAST('' AS DATETIME2))) PERSISTED
  
  
Msg 4936, Level 16, State 1, Line 1  
Computed column 'Date' in table 'QuakeRawJSON' cannot be persisted because the column is non-deterministic.

Answer (score 1):

I found that instead of using CAST ('DateTimeData' as DateTime2) if I use Convert it can be a deterministic result.

As documented on this post: [Cannot persist computed column - not deterministic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14124439/cannot-persist-computed-column-not-deterministic)

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.QuakeRawJSON
ADD [Date]  AS (DATEADD(DAY,DATEDIFF(DAY, CONVERT(DATETIME2,'',112) 
                ,origintime),CONVERT(DATETIME2,'',112))) PERSISTED;
```

Thanks for your help.